Is there a maximum limit for z-score?
I am comparing gene expressions between tumors (n = 44) and normal samples (n = 32) and trying to visualize them through a heatmap. I converted the expressions into z-scores using scale() function on R. I obtained a minimum value of close to -5 and maximum slightly above 8.
I did some search and noticed that usually the z-scores ranged at max between -5 to 5. I have seen that in some cases the sample size affects the maximum of the score, but still, I could not find if anyone else has such high value.
I have previously posted about this on StackOverflow, but it was suggested that a more insightful discussion should take place here.
I know that theoretically, z-scores range from -infinity to infinity, but is there a limit to z-scores in practice?

A normal distribution has support on the whole real number line, so that sense there is no limit, though extreme values are highly unlikely; in general, Chebyshev's inequality give bounds on the probabilities of extreme values for all distributions with finite variances.  However, if you estimate a sample mean $\bar x=\frac 1n\sum x_i$ and sample variance $s^2=\frac1n\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$ or $\frac1{n-1}\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$ , then all the sample observations will have $-\sqrt{n-1} \le \dfrac{x_i -\bar x}{s} \le \sqrt{n-1}$ even though there are no bounds on  $\dfrac{x_i -\mu}{\sigma}$.

@Henry there is, nevertheless., a bound on the z-score computed for any finite list of numbers.  It is attained, as I recall, for binary data in which all but one of the values is zero.  I'm pretty sure it's discussed in a thread here on CV.

@whuber - that leads exactly to the $\pm\sqrt{n-1}$ bounds if you use $s^2=\frac1n\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$

If you computed these on the entirety of your gene expression levels, without accounting for which gene, or what group, and the underlying question is: "Should I be worried?" Then the answer is probably not. A large $z$-score in itself does not mean anything.

Ok, I guess the values are acceptable then...Thanks a lot for your replies!
